# substring return only queried string + 10 char

Tags: mysql, substring

I feel like this shouldn't be this hard, but i want to query a long text field for a string occurence: `"<blog:"`. I want it to return this string, preferably through its ending `">"` Substring_Index doesn't seem to do this for me. Any suggestions?  I currently have:

```
        SELECT body, SUBSTRING(`body`, LOCATE("<blog:", body),20)as blogCat 
        from T1;
```

and this returns EVERYTHING past that string, which is a lot of data. Ideally I'd like it to stop at the first ">" -- is that possible?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, with possibly the example input and output you want? If I am understanding you correctly, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` wouldn't work for you since it returns a substring starting from the left most character up N - 1 characters, where N is equal to the location of a given delimitar. I just want to make sure I am understanding your correctly.

Comment: i added what I have and hopefully that clears it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use LOCATE multiple times

get first > after <
blog and then get only string between these two strings using substring

[`SQL Fiddle`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3011e/6)

```
SELECT body, SUBSTRING(`body`, LOCATE("<blog:", body), 
                       LOCATE(">", body, LOCATE("<blog:", body) ) 
                       - LOCATE("<blog:", body) +1 
                      )as blogCat 
FROM T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're looking to find a substring that occurs between S1 and S2. In that case, try this (I didn't test the syntax):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(body, LOCATE("<blog:", body), LOCATE(">", body, LOCATE("<blog:", body)) - LOCATE("<blog:", body))
FROM
    T1
```

On a side note, I am not sure how, in your example, you're getting all entire string like you're claiming since the you're clearly limiting your substring to 20 characters.

Comment: I realized I left that in there from my tests after I saved the edit.